# I got error as "TemplateError (no implicit conversion of String into Integer)" when i put loop in template file on chef

Tags: loops, templates, chef-infra

This is my attribute file.I want to get the wka members details through the loop.

```
default["clustering"] = {
        "enabled"           => true,
        "membership_scheme" => 'wka',
        "domain"            => 'wr.as.domain',
        "local_member_host" => '10.100.4.777',
        "local_member_port" => '4000',
        "sub_domain"        => 'mgt',
        "wka"               => {
            "members" => [
              {
                "hostname" => '10.100.4.555',
                "port"     => 4000
              },
             {
                "hostname" => '10.100.4.556',
                "port"     => 4000
             }
            ]
        }
    }
```

This is my template file

```
<members>
         <%= node["clustering"]["wka"]["members"].each do |member| -%>
            <member>
                <hostName><%= member['hostname'] %></hostName>
                <port><%= member['port'] %></port>
            </member>
          <% end %>
        </members>
```

Can someone suggest me the right solution for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-printing bits in the template, like loops or conditionals, you use `<%` or `<%-` (the latter trims extra whitespace and is usually what you want), not `<%=`.